# What's the meaning of"reconstruction" and "elements" in the context?

Tags: meaning, interpretation

An article on the topic of idealism claims that, from the idealist point of view:

> The universe can be comprehended through the mind, because both mind and the universe are **reconstructed** of the same **elements**, intellect and spiritual essence.
> https://www.samareducation.com/2022/10/idealism-philosophy.html

What is likely meant by the terms "elements" and "reconstructed" in this passage?

Comment: Welcome to SE. An interesting question, but it would help enormously if you could tell us where your quotation comes from, so that we can take the context into account. Also some indication of what your preliminary guesses (if any) are.

Comment: I'm guessing that quote comes from [here](https://www.samareducation.com/2022/10/idealism-philosophy.html), on the topic of idealism. But the very next paragraph says that idealism "believes" that God is the creator, which I'm pretty sure is just factually incorrect (some idealists may believe in God, but that's not universal). So I probably wouldn't deem that to be a reliable source of information.

Comment: See [Monism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monism)  as well as [Spinoza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baruch_Spinoza): there is only one thin "substance". "He calls this substance "God", or "Nature". In fact, he takes these two terms to be synonymous. For Spinoza the whole of the natural universe is made of one substance, God, or, what is the same, Nature, and its modifications (modes)." Thus, the "external" world and the "internal" mind are both aspects of the same substance.

Comment: So why "reconstructed"? Maybe a typo... both mind and the universe are **constructed** of the same substance: intellect i.e. "spiritual essence" (whatever it may be).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Idealist philosophies, the ultimate grounding of the universe is taken to be mental or spiritual, with the physical and material world being secondary. One common way of conceptualizing this is to say that **the entire material universe exists solely in the mind of God.** However, idealism doesn't necessitate a conventional view of God. In Platonic idealism, for instance, the ultimate grounding of the universe is considered in very abstract, non-anthropomorphic forms, as the "Form of Good."

In the quote you have provided, the "elements" are defined immediately following, within the same sentence, as  "**intellectual and spiritual essence**." This is just another way of expressing the idea that what composes the universe, at its roots, is not physical matter, but something non-corporeal, whether that might be concepts, ideals, or souls.

The term "reconstructed" is a bit misleading, but it expresses the same idea, that **the physical is built from the mental**, and not the other way around. The mind and the body are one substance, and that substance is non-physical. This view of the world has declined in popularity and advocates over the last couple of centuries, but may yet make a comeback in light of the new interest in simulationist theories of existence, which posit that the reality we experience might be a computer simulation, and thus not directly founded on a material reality.

Comment: I wouldn't say there's a *lot* of interest in simulation theories. Usually it's a go-to example of a claim we should reject due to it's lack of explanatory power and it's unfalsifiability. You'll find few names of proponents on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulation_hypothesis), beyond the person who popularised it (and Elon Musk, but who cares).

Comment: @NotThatGuy - I didn't say "a lot" of interest. With that said, I expect they will become more compelling as the technology behind simulations grows better, and it becomes harder-and-harder to distinguish the experience they provide from reality (or should that be "reality"?).